# Proibir usuário a cadastrar 2 usuários com emails e matriculas iguais

Tags: php, html, mysql

**Eu queria que quando o usuários fosse se registrar, se ele informa-se um email ou matricula já existente no banco desse uma mensagem e proibi-se ele se registrar no sistema, no código abaixo ele continua registrando o usuário mesmo com os campos email e matricula já existente no banco de dados.**

```
<?php 

include("includes/conexao.php");//conexão com o banco

if(isset($_POST["registrar"])) {
    //Busca no banco a quantidade de usuarios que tenham a mesma matricula OU o mesmo email
    $querySelect = "SELECT count(*) total FROM usuarios WHERE matricula = {$_POST['matricula']} or email = {$_POST['email']}";


     //prepara a query
    $statement = $connection->prepare($querySelect);

    //executar o comando sql
    $result = $statement->execute();

    //juntar todos os resultados do select em um vetor de arrays
    $result = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    //Verificase o valor retornado é 0 (Nenhum usuário igual cadastrado)
    if($result['total'] == 0){

        $senha           = $_POST['senha'];
        $confirma_senha  = $_POST['confirma_senha'];
        if (empty($senha)) {
            $mensagem = "<span class='aviso'><b>Aviso</b>: Senha não foi alterada!</span>";
        } else if ($senha == $confirma_senha) {
            $query = "INSERT INTO usuario (nome, sobrenome, matricula, email, senha) 
                  VALUES (:nome, :sobrenome, :matricula, :email, :senha)";

            $statement = $connection->prepare($query);


            $valores = array();
            $valores[':nome'] = (isset($_POST['primeiroNome']) ? $_POST['primeiroNome'] : '');
            $valores[':sobrenome'] = (isset($_POST['sobrenome']) ? $_POST['sobrenome'] : '');
            $valores[':matricula'] = (isset($_POST['matricula']) ? $_POST['matricula'] : '');
            $valores[':email'] = (isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : '');
            $valores[':senha'] = (isset($_POST['senha']) ? $_POST['senha'] : '');

            $result = $statement->execute($valores);
            if(!empty($result)){
                $mensagem = "<span class='aviso'><b>Sucesso</b>: deu certo!</span>";
            }
        } else {
             $mensagem = "<span class='aviso'><b>Aviso</b>: Senha e repetir senha são diferentes!</span>";

        }

    }else{
        $mensagem = "<span class='aviso'><b>Erro</b>: Email ou matricula ja cadastrado!</span>";
    }

}


?>
```

**Caso queira ver como está o meu formulário.**

```
<form method="POST" action="registro.php" onsubmit="return validarSenha()"name="formulario">
            <div class="form-group">
               <div class="form-row">
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                     <label for="primeiroNome">Primeiro nome</label>
                     <input type="text" class="form-control" id="primeiroNome" name="primeiroNome" placeholder="Digite seu primeiro nome" required="required">
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                     <label for="Sobrenome">Sobrenome</label>
                     <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Sobrenome" name="sobrenome" placeholder="Digite seu Sobrenome" required="required" autofocus="autofocus">
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6" id="matricula">
               <label for="primeiroNome">Matrícula</label>
               <input type="text" class="form-control"  name="matricula" placeholder="Digite sua matrícula" required="required" autofocus="autofocus">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
               <label for="email">E-mail</label>
               <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Digite seu email" required="required" autofocus="autofocus">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
               <div class="form-row">
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                     <label for="senha">Senha</label>
                     <input type="password" class="form-control" id="senha" name="senha" placeholder="Digite sua senha" required="required" autofocus="autofocus">
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                     <label for="confirma_senha">confirmar senha</label>
                     <input type="password"  class="form-control" id="confirmaSenha" name="confirma_senha" placeholder="Confirme sua senha" required="required" autofocus="autofocus">
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div>
               <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" name="registrar" value="Registra-se"/>
            </div>
            <div class="text-center">
               <a href="#" class="d-block small mt-3">Esqueceu sua senha?</a>
               <a href="login.php" class="d-block small mt-3">Login?</a>
            </div>
         </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que o result['total'], esteja retornando um array. use um count() para comparar

```
 if(count($result) == 0){
```

Comment: continua registrando dados já existente agora aparece esse erro: Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in C:\xampp\htdocs\nsi\registro.php on line 20

Comment: Então faça sem o count no sql e use o num rows assim :   $querySelect = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE matricula = {$_POST['matricula']} or email = {$_POST['email']}";
depois 
$result = $statement->execute();
$result = $result->fetchColumn()